# Using the Toothpick DI framework be used with a Java (only) project

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-injection, annotation-processing, toothpick-di

I started a small *proof of concept* exercise to make us of the [Toothpick DI framework](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick) with an existing Gradle based Java project.  I have read quite a few claims that you can use Toothpick with Java (meaning the JRE, OpenJDK, JDK or JSE - No Android) ... However, every example I've been able to check/work through has at some point a dependency on Android in some way, shape or `configuration`.

With the most (*partially*) successful effort so far has been to use an experimental, throw-away Android mocking package to have my Java project at least compile without error.  That said it comes-up blank on resolving any should-be generated dependencies, such as the:

- generated `MemberInjectorRegistry`
- generated `FactoryRegistry`

The Toothpick sample project itself and the simpler of the available examples all use an Android configuration and often as not dependencies on other Android specifics.

### update Two

I took direction to the [Toothpick sample](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/tree/master/toothpick-sample) project, a Java project

- https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/tree/master/toothpick-sample

The Tootpick wiki and the sample project use the Java compile option:

```
     compileJava {
           options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
           options.compilerArgs = ['-Atoothpick_registry_package_name=experiments.toothpick',]
     }
```

That gave me a warning that turned-out to be a mismatch in Gradle and plugins.  And I needed a new build with `--refresh-dependencies` (*hint*: make sure you compile the TestsPackages).

After fixing that the sample compiles and passes the Unit Tests.  The generated files are under `build/generated` and I managed to encourage Netbeans to *find* them with this:

```
 sourceSets {
     generated {
         java {
             srcDirs = [ 'build/generated/source/apt/main' ];
         }
     }
 }
```

Sadly Netbeans continues to put  little red-lines under the generated symbols.  At least it runs.  Netbeans support could be better.

My earlier experiment looked on the Toothpick `Smoothie` which is an Android  example.  Kind of interesting as an intellectual exercise ...

- [Smoothie sample](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/tree/master/smoothie)

That `build.gradle` file relies on Android.  So I tried mock substitutes for  missing components.  The project compiles but can't find (*any*) generated code.

I would have considered by now that there might be at least ONE successful Java JRE/JDK Toothpick project example '*out there*'.

### update        One

I decided to tackle this from the *other end* and look to the common Java annotation processing examples.  This works as far as I got, with Gradle v**4.7** (and also I think v4.6).

In your (sub-)project `build.gradle` ...

```
    plugins {
        id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"
    }
       :

    dependencies {
         annotationProcessor (
             dep_toothpickCompiler
         )
       :
    }
```

The `dep_toothpickCompiler` is defined earlier as:

```
 //      Annotation Processor    
     dep_toothpickCompiler   = "com.github.stephanenicolas.toothpick:toothpick-compiler:${ver_toothpick}"
```

***results*** ...

This step at least managed to create a

- `build/generated` folder

Unfortunately no generated output so far.  There is light at the end of the tunnel, I'm sure.  I'll post updates here if/as I get closer to a *solution*.

---

**learning examples** (GitHub)

I've identified some 'reliable' Toothpick examples.  So far they want Android in there some place.  Either as Android targeted modules or using related dependencies.

- https://github.com/davidbcn/ToothpickWorkshop
- https://github.com/WarrenFaith/Toothpick-Sample
- https://github.com/wongcain/okuki
- https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=toothpick&type=Repositories

Given (or assuming) that a pure Java / Toothpick project can build, debug and run on the desktop or from the command line; it doesn't seem to be a popular choice as far as my *googling* went ...

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the TP sample, it is pure Java.

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/tree/master/toothpick-sample

Smoothie is actually the android specific part of TP.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Found the [Toothpick sample](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/toothpick/tree/master/toothpick-sample) ... I builds with this warning: `Task :plumbing:compileJava FAILED
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[toothpick_registry_package_name]'`.  I doubt that the Toothpick sample will build as a subproject because the main project is an Android project.

Comment: As you see it eventually worked as a separate project, once the dependencies and plugins were sorted out.  I'd be interested if someone has a "_fix_" for netbeans to include the generated code in the syntax checking.

Comment: What do you mean by syntax checking ? Indeed TP should not behave differently at this level than any other annotation processor that generates code.

Comment: Hi AspectJ and Dagger had the same problem -- It is a _known about_ Netbeans thing.  There is an option for Ant builds to get around it.  Lombok seems to be OK but they put their code in a different place from memory(??).  The important thing is that it works fine.